# Automated testing with monkeyrunner and checking outcome

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner, automated-tests

I want to automate some testing of application and I want to click on some button (brn1) but then if textview1 have value of "A" I want to make press on btn2 else if the textview have value of "B" I want the script to make click on btn3.

I know how to connect with device how to make click at certain position (to click the button) but I do not know how to check the value of some text view and how to make decision in the script (how to construct if statement)

Does monkeyrunner have support for this ? if it doesn't then what should I do, or maybe there is no support for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value which is come after click on the button then you can't get it. Because MonkeRunner doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [Selenium AndroidDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver) is more suitable for such testing activities.